# Adding an arbitrary line to a matplotlib plot in ipython notebook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I'm rather new to both python/matplotlib and using it through the ipython notebook. I'm trying to add some annotation lines to an existing graph and I can't figure out how to render the lines on a graph. So, for example, if I plot the following:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5)
x = arange(1, 101)
y = 20 + 3 * x + np.random.normal(0, 60, 100)
p =  plot(x, y, "o")
```

I get the following graph:

[image: beautiful scatter plot]

So how would I add a vertical line from (70,100) up to (70,250)? What about a diagonal line from (70,100) to (90,200)?

I've tried a few things with `Line2D()` resulting in nothing but confusion on my part. In `R` I would simply use the segments() function which would add line segments. Is there an equivalent in `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You can directly plot the lines you want by feeding the `plot` command with the corresponding data (boundaries of the segments):

`plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], color='k', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)`

(of course you can choose the color, line width, line style, etc.)

From your example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
x = np.arange(1, 101)
y = 20 + 3 * x + np.random.normal(0, 60, 100)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")


# draw vertical line from (70,100) to (70, 250)
plt.plot([70, 70], [100, 250], 'k-', lw=2)

# draw diagonal line from (70, 90) to (90, 200)
plt.plot([70, 90], [90, 200], 'k-')

plt.show()
```

[image: new chart]

Comment: Minor correction, the code above should read `x = np.arange(1, 101)`.

Comment: This will not draw a line, but only a segment.  The question how to draw a line throw two given points remains unanswered.

Comment: The problem I see that these segments will be accounted as plots, disrupting legends....

Comment: @Rmano you can avoid the segments to be taken in account in the legend by adding a label argument starting with "_". Ex: `plt.plot([70, 70], [100, 250], 'k-', lw=2, label="_not in legend")`

Comment: how to do this when the xvalue is a date?

Comment: The fact that `90` is used both as `x2` and and `y1` leads to a lot of ambiguity.
For anyone viewing this, note that `[70, 90]` does not refer to a single point at location `x1,y1`.

For reference, here are the meanings of the values:
`[x1: 70, x2: 90], [y1: 90, y2: 200]`

Comment: Works on images too

Comment: @pookie I agree. This confused me for a while. Someone please approve my edit for clarification.

Answer (score 86):

It's not too late for the [newcomers](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline).

```
plt.axvline(x, color='r') # vertical
plt.axhline(x, color='r') # horizontal
```

It takes the range of `y` as well, using `ymin` and `ymax`.

Comment: The min/max parameters of axhline and axvline are scalar values between 0 and 1 that plot lines in reference to the plot's edge. Although a good tool, it's probably not a the best solution to the author's problem statement of drawing annotation lines.

Comment: This is perfect for wanting to add an annotation line in the background that spans the whole graph. If I use the chosen solution above to draw a vertical line at x=1, I have to specify the min and max y, and then the plot resizes automatically with a buffer, so the line doesn't stretch across the entire plot, and that's a hassle. This is more elegant and doesn't resize the plot.

Answer (score 42):

Using [`vlines`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5)
x = arange(1, 101)
y = 20 + 3 * x + np.random.normal(0, 60, 100)
p =  plot(x, y, "o")
vlines(70,100,250)
```

The basic call signatures are:

```
vlines(x, ymin, ymax)
hlines(y, xmin, xmax)
```

Comment: that's excellent. I had not seen the `vline()` or `hline()` functions. What about diagonal lines? I edited the question to add the diagonal bit now that you've shown me the h & v lines.

Comment: Try making a `DataFrame` containing the x,y coordinates and plotting them with `style='k-'`

Answer (score 13):

Rather than abusing `plot` or `annotate`, which will be inefficient for many lines, you can use [`matplotlib.collections.LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

np.random.seed(5)
x = np.arange(1, 101)
y = 20 + 3 * x + np.random.normal(0, 60, 100)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")

# Takes list of lines, where each line is a sequence of coordinates
l1 = [(70, 100), (70, 250)]
l2 = [(70, 90), (90, 200)]
lc = LineCollection([l1, l2], color=["k","blue"], lw=2)

plt.gca().add_collection(lc)

plt.show()
```

[image: Figure with two lines plotted via LineCollection]

It takes a list of lines `[l1, l2, ...]`, where each line is a sequence of *N* coordinates (*N* can be more than two).

The standard formatting keywords are available, accepting either a single value, in which case the value applies to every line, or a sequence of *M* `values`, in which case the value for the *i*th line is `values[i % M]`.

Answer (score 10):

Matplolib now allows for 'annotation lines' as the OP was seeking. The `annotate()` function allows several forms of connecting paths and a headless and tailess arrow, i.e., a simple line, is one of them.

```
ax.annotate("",
            xy=(0.2, 0.2), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(0.8, 0.8), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",
                      connectionstyle="arc3, rad=0"),
            )
```

In [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html#annotating-with-arrow) it says you can draw only an arrow with an empty string as the first argument.

From the OP's example:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
x = np.arange(1, 101)
y = 20 + 3 * x + np.random.normal(0, 60, 100)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")


# draw vertical line from (70,100) to (70, 250)
plt.annotate("",
              xy=(70, 100), xycoords='data',
              xytext=(70, 250), textcoords='data',
              arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",
                              connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0."), 
              )

# draw diagonal line from (70, 90) to (90, 200)
plt.annotate("",
              xy=(70, 90), xycoords='data',
              xytext=(90, 200), textcoords='data',
              arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",
                              connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0."), 
              )

plt.show()
```

[image: Example inline image]

Just as in the approach in gcalmettes's answer, you can choose the color, line width, line style, etc..

Here is an alteration to a portion of the code that would make one of the two example lines red, wider, and not 100% opaque.

```
# draw vertical line from (70,100) to (70, 250)
plt.annotate("",
              xy=(70, 100), xycoords='data',
              xytext=(70, 250), textcoords='data',
              arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-",
                              edgecolor = "red",
                              linewidth=5,
                              alpha=0.65,
                              connectionstyle="arc3,rad=0."), 
              )
```

You can also add curve to the connecting line by adjusting the `connectionstyle`.