# Plot some numbers in x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

My question is related to the figure format generated using the matplotlib library.

So, in the x axis, I have the integers from 1 to 100, but in my code I plot just the data related to some numbers (e.g 1,5,77,86,97).

At the end, my code shows me a figure with x axis from 1 to 100.

How can I show just the needed numbers (1,5,77,86,97)?

My code is shown below:

```
def Plot(self,x,y, steps, nb,bool):  
    if(bool == False):

        labelfont = {
                'family' : 'sans-serif',  # (cursive, fantasy, monospace, serif)
                'color'  : 'black',       # html hex or colour name
                'weight' : 'normal',      # (normal, bold, bolder, lighter)
                'size'   : 20,            # default value:12
                }

        titlefont = {
                'family' : 'serif',
                'color'  : 'black',
                'weight' : 'bold',
                'size'   : 20,
                }

        x = np.array(x)
        y = np.array(y)
        pylab.plot(x, y,
                 'darkmagenta',                       # colour
                 linestyle='',                      # line style
                 linewidth=10,                       # line width
                 marker = '+',
                 mew=6, ms=12)

        axes = plt.gca()
        axes.grid(True)
        axes.set_xlim([1, x_max)            # x-axis bounds
        axes.set_ylim([1, nb])              # y-axis bounds

        pylab.title('Title' , fontdict=titlefont)
        pylab.xlabel('x', fontdict=labelfont)
        pylab.ylabel('y', fontdict=labelfont)

        pylab.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)        # prevents overlapping of the y label
    else:
        test_steps.insert(0,"")
        pylab.yticks(nb,  steps,rotation=0, size=10)
        pylab.margins(0.2)
        pylab.xticks(np.arange(0, x_max, 1.0),rotation=90, size=10)
        # Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of tick-labels
        pylab.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
        F = pylab.gcf()
        DefaultSize = F.get_size_inches()
        if x_max < 100 and len(steps) < 100:
            Xx = 2.5
            Yy = 2.5
        elif x_max < 200 and len(steps) < 200:
            Xx = 5
            Yy = 5
        elif ix_max < 300 and len(steps) < 300:
            Xx = 8
            Yy = 8
        elif x_max < 400 and steps < 400:
            Xx = 10
            Yy = 10
        elif x_max < 500 and steps < 500:
            Xx = 12
            Yy = 12
        else:
            Xx = 15
            Yy = 15
        F.set_size_inches((DefaultSize[0]*Xx , DefaultSize[1]*Yy))
        F.savefig('Out.png', bbox_inches='tight')
        pylab.close(F)
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @DavidG: I edited my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = y = list(range(100))
idx = [1,5,77,86,97]
new_y = [y[i] for i in idx]
plt.plot(range(len(idx)), new_y, 'o-')
plt.xticks(range(len(idx)),idx)
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

If you want only dots just remove the `-`:

```
plt.plot(range(len(idx)), new_y, 'o')
#                              ---^--- instead of 'o-'
```

Comment: Nice, that simplifies things

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `matplotlib.Axes` object you can modify the ticks along the x-axis with `set_xticks`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1,5,77,86,97],range(6),'o-')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([1,5,77,86,97])
```

with output:

[image]

**EDIT**: assuming you want to plot the values equally separated (though at this point you really should be considering something like bar graphs with the numbers as labels), you could just make a fake x-axis and rename the ticks using `set_xticklabels`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(5)
y = range(5)
real_x = [1,5,77,86,97]
plt.plot(x,y,'o-')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(real_x)
```

[image]

Comment: What I mean is that the distance between 1 and 5, 5 and 77, 77 and 86... should be the same.

Comment: @StackOver So what you would want, is that they are equally spaced even if the difference between them is not the same? You would want the example plot I have above to show a straight line?

Comment: No, not a straight line, just  points. The curve is not continuous. like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864294/adding-an-arbitrary-line-to-a-matplotlib-plot-in-ipython-notebook

Answer (score 0):

How about masking x with y and then plotting it?
like:

```
pylap.plot(x[y != 0], y,
             'darkmagenta',                       # colour
             linestyle='',                      # line style
             linewidth=10,                       # line width
             marker = '+',
             mew=6, ms=12)
```

Or if y contains more numbers != 0 and you only want to plot those listed above, just mask x with these numbers...