# Adding an arbitrary line to a matplotlib plot with datetimes on x axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I've found a way to draw a line (not necessary vertical or horizontal) in a matplotlib plot: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864294/adding-an-arbitrary-line-to-a-matplotlib-plot-in-ipython-notebook) recommends using

```
plt.plot([2, 3], [25, 10])
```

However that does not work with plot with datetimes on the x axis.

I'm getting "ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1" with all the attempts in the following code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from calendar import monthrange
import datetime

def get_datetime_range(year, month): # Create a list with all days in a month
    nb_days = monthrange(year, month)[1]
    return [datetime.date(year, month, day) for day in range(1, nb_days+1)]    

# Create sample data
date = get_datetime_range(2017, 9)
value = [d.day % 12 for d in date]

# Draw
plt.plot(date, value)

plt.axvline(date[10], color='r', zorder=0) # Vertical line works

m = len(date)-1
print("Draw line from [%s, %s] to [%s, %s]." % (date[0], value[0], date[m], value[m]))

# The following does NOT work

plt.plot_date([date[0], value[0]], 
              [date[m], value[m]]) # Gives ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

#plt.plot([date[10], 1], 
#         [date[25], 20])


#plt.plot_date([date2num(date[0]), value[0]], 
#              [date2num(date[m]), value[m]])

#plt.plot([2, 3], [25, 10])

plt.plot()
```

I also tried converting the datetimes to number with date2num without success (the same error):

```
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

dateNum = [date2num(d) for d in date]
plt.plot(dateNum, value) # Works

plt.axvline(date[10], color='r', zorder=0) # Works

plt.plot_date([date2num(date[0]), value[0]],  
              [date2num(date[m]), value[m]]) # Gives ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because you have got the order of your coordinates slightly wrong. With:

```
plt.plot_date([date[0], value[0]], 
              [date[m], value[m]])
```

You are saying that your x coordinates are `date[0]` and `value[0]`. Whereas your x coordinates are actually `date[0]` and `date[m]`. Therefore, you should use:

```
plt.plot_date([date[0],date[m]],
              [value[0], value[m]])
```

The full code:

```
def get_datetime_range(year, month): # Create a list with all days in a month
    nb_days = monthrange(year, month)[1]
    return [datetime.date(year, month, day) for day in range(1, nb_days+1)]

# Create sample data
date = get_datetime_range(2017, 9)
value = [d.day % 12 for d in date]

# Draw
plt.plot(date, value)

plt.axvline(date[10], color='r', zorder=0) # Vertical line works

m = len(date)-1
print("Draw line from [%s, %s] to [%s, %s]." % (date[0], value[0], date[m], value[m]))

# changes were made here
plt.plot_date([date[0], date[m]], [value[0], value[m]], fmt='-', color='r')

plt.show()
```

Gives the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The format is `plot([x1, x2, x3, ...], [y1, y2, y3, ...])`. In your code you have `plot_date([x1, y1], [x2, y2])`, which is incorrect.

replacing your code with:

```
plt.plot_date([date[0], date[m]], 
              [value[0], value[m]])
```

solves the problem.

Note, however, [that the default behavior of `plot_date()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date.html?highlight=matplotlib%20axes%20axes%20plot_date#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date) is to plot points (`fmt='o'`) and not a line. If you want a line, as your code implies, you need to change the format argument:

```
plt.plot_date([date[0], date[m]], 
              [value[0], value[m]], fmt='-')
```